# Django custom context processor passes incorrect data to home template only

Tags: django, jinja2

I'm working on a project which I require to show category menu on every page.
So I decided to use a context processor for that as shown below:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def product_categories(request):
    from shopadmin.models import ProductCategory
    categories = ProductCategory.objects.all()
    logger.info(f'CATEGORIES ARE: {categories}')
    return {'product_categories': categories}
```

And I show the categories with following code in base.html

```
{% if product_categories %}
  <div class="categories_menu_toggle">
    <ul> 
      {% for category in product_categories %}
        {% if category.is_root_category %}
          <li class="menu_item_children categorie_list"><a href="#"><span><i class="zmdi zmdi-desktop-mac"></i></span>{{ category.title }}<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            {% if category.sub_categories.all %}
              <ul class="categories_mega_menu">
                {% for sub_category in category.sub_categories.all %}

                  <li class="menu_item_children"><a href="#">{{ sub_category.title }}</a>
                    {% if sub_category.sub_categories %}
                      <ul class="categorie_sub_menu">
                        {% for child_category in sub_category.sub_categories.all %}
                          <li><a href="">{{ child_category.title }}</a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </ul>
                    {% endif %}
                  </li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            {% endif %}
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      <li id="cat_toggle" class="has-sub"><a href="#"> {% trans 'More Categories' %}</a>
        <ul class="categorie_sub">
          <li><a href="#"><span><i class="zmdi zmdi-gamepad"></i></span> {% trans 'Hide Categories' %}</a></li>
        </ul>   

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

home.html, products.html, product.html, invoice.html and almost all other templates extend base.html template.
But something happens here that I can not understand.
When I open the homepage (index), the result of the logger.info(...) from context_processor is:

```
[context_processors.py line:9 product_categories] -> (INFO): CATEGORIES ARE: <QuerySet [<ProductCategory: new Category>, <ProductCategory: Parent Category>, <ProductCategory: Level One category>, <ProductCategory:  Level Two Category>, <ProductCategory: Level Three Category>]>
```

which is the sample data I entered. But I Only get some of them on index page. 
I added {% debug %} in home.html and products.html
and the result was:

home.html:

```
 'product_categories': <QuerySet [<ProductCategory: Level Three Category>, <ProductCategory:  Level Two Category>, <ProductCategory: Level One category>]>,
```

products.html:

```
 'product_categories': <QuerySet [<ProductCategory: new Category>, <ProductCategory: Parent Category>, <ProductCategory: Level One category>, <ProductCategory:  Level Two Category>, <ProductCategory: Level Three Category>]>,
```

So. some categories are not passed to template in home.html but that works on all other pages the way it was intended to work.

So, can anyone help me with this?! 
What's happening here?

Comment: Do you by any chance pass `product_categories` in the *view* (that thus override the ones in the context-processor)?

Comment: That was totally it ... Gosh I feel stupid ... some other developer on the team was passing product_categories as context for modified list of ProductCategory and that totally affected what I was trying to do ... I can't believe I lost a whole day on it :(. Thanks @WillemVanOnsem <3